# Microsoft Edge JS userAgent Detection Incomplete

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to detect when a user is on Microsoft Edge. I have a Windows 10 install running on VirtualBox. When I use the developer tools in Edge's console to check the userAgent string, this is all it returns:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"

With Internet Explorer 11 on the same Windows install, the console correctly reports this:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

So why is Edge refusing to identify itself? Anyone run into this before?

Comment: On my system, it says `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10532`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems I've fixed my own issue. I had to setup a new user account on Windows 10. After logging into the new account, Microsoft Edge now reports the userAgent string correctly:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240"

Bizarre issue. Hope this is helpful to anyone else who runs across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does identify itself. It should return much more info than what you posted. Are you sure you're using the latest MS Edge?

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The Microsoft Edge for desktop in Windows 10 and RemoteIE builds is
>   designed for maximum interoperability with other modern browsers and
>   contemporary web content. It has the following user-agent string:
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.

Notice the `Edge/12.(OS build number)` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, that's the string I expected, but for some reason, my copy of Edge refuses to display anything more than what I posted above. I just ran it through Windows Update to no avail. I wonder if it has something to do with VirtualBox? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I cannot think of anything in VirtualBox that affects the browser.